# Efficient way to query multiple terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query a field for exact match that returns multiple documents. I'm not sure which of the following options is more efficient.

Option 1: with just a simple terms query, Option 2: OR within a bool, Option 3: filter query within a query

````
"query": {
    "terms": {
      "filed01.name": [
        "ABC",
        "DEF"
      ]
    }
  }

Option 2:
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field01.name": "ABC"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field01.name": "DEF"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

Option 3:
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "field01.name": [
            "ABC",
            "DEF"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: do you want to have `ABC` and `DEF` versus `ABC` or `DEF`? do you also care about document scoring? (how well that document matched with your search criteria)?

Comment: @JBone its ABC or DEF. They must be exact matches and hence I'm contemplating to use 'filter' if it helps. no scoring required.

Comment: ok good, so that leaves option 1 and 3 out. in the option 2, you can use `term` instead of `match` to avoid the scoring. and may be add `minumum_should_match: 1`

Comment: @JBone why would option 1 and 3 not good? they give the same result.

Comment: Option 1 is out because it's using a scoring query (i.e. - it's not nested within either a bool's `filter` clause OR a `constant_score` query).  I'm not sure why @JBone is saying Option 3 is out - that's actually the route I'd suggest, because it's running an exact, non-analyzed match (`terms`) in a non-scoring query (`bool.filter`) that ORs your search terms as requested (by virtue of how a `terms` query works when multiple terms are specified)

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest to go for query+filter+terms since you want exact match with any of ABC OR DEF.